# Domain Name When querying DNS server

Tags: java, networking, dns

When querying DNS server for the IP address, which one of the following is a valid domain name (or host name)? I want to write a program in Java to Query the DNS Server for the IP address of a given host.

```
www.google.com
OR 
google.com
```

Comment: With my program if i query to get the 'A' record for google.com, the answer section in the response has the IPv4 Address. If I query for the www.google.com 'A' record, I get the 'CNAME' response back from the DNS Server. One interesting difference I noticed is www.google.com has aliases. I do the query for www.cnn.com or just cnn.com, the result is the same. CNN doesn't have any aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try both? They might have same set of [resource records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System), they might be different, or one might be an alias for the other. In reality they are different:

```
nickf@gloin:~$ host google.com
google.com has address 72.14.204.99
google.com has address 72.14.204.104
google.com has address 72.14.204.103
google.com has address 72.14.204.147
google.com mail is handled by 100 google.com.s9a1.psmtp.com.
google.com mail is handled by 300 google.com.s9b1.psmtp.com.
google.com mail is handled by 400 google.com.s9b2.psmtp.com.
google.com mail is handled by 200 google.com.s9a2.psmtp.com.

nickf@gloin:~$ host www.google.com
www.google.com is an alias for www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com has address 72.14.204.147
www.l.google.com has address 72.14.204.103
www.l.google.com has address 72.14.204.99
www.l.google.com has address 72.14.204.104
```

Comment: With my program if i query to get the 'A' record for google.com, the answer section in the response has the IPv4 Address. If I query for the www.google.com 'A' record, I get the 'CNAME' response back from the DNS Server. One interesting difference I noticed is www.google.com has aliases. I do the query for www.cnn.com or just cnn.com, the result is the same. CNN doesn't have any aliases.

Comment: It's up to DNS admin to lay this out. There're no definite rules. `www` here might be a host name within the domain, or a subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

> `google.com` == domain --> resolve to server-IP mapped to `google.com`
>
> `www.google.com` == subdomain  --> resolve to server-IP mapped to `www.google.com`

If they have configured the same you will get same result, else different. But both are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid hostnames as far as DNS is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

They might be both valid.

If you want to check whether google.com, www.google.com, wwwwwww.goo.g.le.com are valid, the best thing is to query the DNS server.